# SQL query not giving expected result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im using this query to get data from table with these conditions but query giving me unexpected data. This is my SQL query.

```
SELECT userCode, email, isSubscribe FROM users WHERE 1 
    AND (city = 'Boston' AND stateCode = '3fe5003edc0cb6c83962dbd74d35dd50' AND zipcode = '32564')
    OR accountType = 'O' 
    OR helpMoreType = 'DI' 
    OR helpMoreType = 'CO' 
    OR helpMoreType = 'AD'
    AND accountStatus = 'A' 
    AND isSubscribe = 'Y' 
    AND accountType != 'S'
```

It show an unexpected record having `isSubscribe = N`

After modification on SQL query it show exact data what I want and modified query is:

```
SELECT userCode, email, isSubscribe FROM users WHERE 1 
AND (city = 'Boston' AND stateCode = '3fe5003edc0cb6c83962dbd74d35dd50' AND zipcode = '32564')
OR (accountType = 'O' 
OR helpMoreType = 'DI' 
OR helpMoreType = 'CO' 
OR helpMoreType = 'AD')
AND accountStatus = 'A' 
AND isSubscribe = 'Y' 
AND accountType != 'S'
```

But I am unable to understand what is difference between both query? Can anyone point out on both query?

Thank You

Comment: Look up [operator precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html). I suspect your query is still wrong.

Comment: The query is still wrong and may still give you records having `isSubscribe = N`.

Comment: @skelwa: Im not getting record with isSubscribe = N after modification in query

Comment: Would you like tea or biscuits? Would you like tea and biscuits?

Comment: @Strawberry I like tea or biscuits with isSubcribe = Y

Comment: @anil : That's why i said `may still give` you records having isSubscribe = N. Check the fiddle for sample data where your query fails :: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b58ad/1

Comment: @skelwa: Okay then what will be correct order to write this SQL?

Comment: In the fiddle, if you change the `OR` that is in front of the parenthesis to an `AND`, do you get the output that you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `OR` expressions are not constrained within parenthesis, it is saying that any record which meets one of the conditions separated by `OR` is valid to return.

When you bound them inside of parenthesis, you create a single condition that relies on multiple possible criteria to satisfy the condition.

As an example, if you think about some real world objects:

*"Buy a fruit and a vegetable"*, defined as, *"A Banana"* `OR` *"An Apple"* `OR` *"An Orange"* `AND` *"An Onion"*, means that if you purchase any of the fruits, you have satisfied the condition since *"A Banana"* will evaluate to `True` and move on to the next row.

Defined instead as, (*"A Banana"* `OR` *"An Apple"* `OR` *"An Orange"*) `AND` *"An Onion"*, means that you can purchase any of the three fruits but **must** also purchase an *"An Onion"* in order for the condition to evaluate to `True`.

Comment: Why isSubscribe = 'Y' condition is not working with all OR operator? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: When you are using only `OR` operators, without the enclosing parentheses, your query potentially isn't even evaluating `isSubscribe = 'Y'`. In the event that `helpMoreType = 'DI' ` for a given row, it's selected without even moving on to the remaining rows, because it satisfies the conditional expression.